# How to preload a javascript dependency via Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is it possible to inject the dependency via jest or alternative without having to import 'lib' into the file itself?

**Example file.js**

```js
// Note: lib is not defined in this file
export const getDep = (str) => {
  lib('something'); 
 return str;
}
```

**Example jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    window: {
      lib: () => {} // does not work
    },
    lib: () => {} // does not work
  },
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest/setupFiles.js'], // doesnt work either
  // ...other stuff
}
```

**Example jest/setupFiles.js**

```
const lib = () => {};
console.log(lib);
```

**Example file.test.js**

```js
import { getDep } from "file.js";

describe('Test injection of global dependency using jest.config', () => {
  it("should not break test", () => {
    const result = getDep('hello');
    expect(result).toEqual('hello')
  })
})
```

Also tried jest - setupFiles

> Error ReferenceError: lib is not defined

```
  1 |
  2 | export const getDep = (str) => {
> 3 |   lib('something');
    |   ^
  4 |  return str;
```

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array (or `...AfterEnv`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe doesn't work. will update my examples above to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @jonrsharpe for a partial successful solution.
I had to use jest setupFiles, but also I had to add the dependency to the window object.

**window.lib = lib;**

```js
const lib = () => {};
window.lib = lib; // Added code here..
console.log(lib);
```